# self.root.ids.slide.load_next(mode="next") AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am learning to work on kivymd and tried to run a simple code but getting the same error everytime after clicking on next button of the code,can anyone help me resolve this error

reg_customer.kv file:-

```
MDScreen:
    name:"customer"
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDCard:
            size_hint: .8, .9
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
            Carousel:
                id: slide
                MDFloatLayout:
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"First Name"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.57}
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Last Name"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.46}
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Aadhar No."
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.26}
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Phone Number"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.36}

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "next"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.13}
                        on_release:
                            app.next()
                MDFloatLayout:

                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"House No."
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.57}
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Locality"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.46}
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Area, colony"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.36}
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Pincode"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.26}
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "PREVIOUS"
                        size_hint_x:.39
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.3, 'center_y':.15}
                        on_release:
                            app.previous()
                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "NEXT"
                        size_hint_x:.39
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.7, 'center_y':.15}
                        on_release:
                            app.next1()

                MDFloatLayout:
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Password"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.57}
                        password: True
                    MDTextField:
                        hint_text:"Confirm Password"
                        size_hint_x:.8
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.46}
                        password: True

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "PREVIOUS"
                        size_hint_x:.39
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.3, 'center_y':.2}
                        on_release:
                            app.previous1()

                    MDRaisedButton:
                        text: "SUBMIT"
                        size_hint_x:.39
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.7, 'center_y':.2}
                        on_release:
                            app.submit()

    MDLabel:
        text: "Register as Customer"
        bold: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.67, 'center_y':.85}
        font_style:"H5"

    MDLabel:
        id: info
        text:"Personal Info"
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.7, 'center_y':.7}
        font_size:"13sp"
        bold:True
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
    MDIconButton:
        id: icon
        icon:"numeric-1-circle"
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.25,'center_y':.65}
        user_font_size:"35sp"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
    MDProgressBar:
        id: progress
        size_hint:.16, .009
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.37,'center_y':.65}
    MDLabel:
        id: address
        text:"Address"
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.96, 'center_y':.7}
        font_size:"13sp"
        bold:True
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
    MDIconButton:
        id: icon1
        icon:"numeric-2-circle"
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.65}
        user_font_size:"35sp"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
    MDProgressBar:
        id: progress1
        size_hint:.16, .009
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.62,'center_y':.65}
    MDLabel:
        id: finish
        text:"Finish"
        pos_hint:{'center_x':1.2, 'center_y':.7}
        font_size:"13sp"
        bold:True
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
    MDIconButton:
        id: icon2
        icon:"numeric-3-circle"
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.75,'center_y':.65}
        user_font_size:"35sp"
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
```

customer.py file :-

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (350, 580)



class customer_page(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("reg_customer.kv"))
        return screen_manager

    def next(self):
        self.root.ids.slide.load_next(mode="next")
        self.root.ids.info.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.ids.progress.value = 100
        self.root.ids.icon.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.ids.icon.icon = "check-decagram"

    def next1(self):
        self.root.ids.slide.load_next(mode="next")
        self.root.ids.address.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.ids.progress1.value = 100
        self.root.ids.icon1.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.ids.icon1.icon = "check-decagram"

    def submit(self):
        self.root.ids.slide.load_next(mode="next")
        self.root.ids.finish.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.ids.icon2.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color
        self.root.ids.icon2.icon = "check-decagram"


    def previous(self):
        self.root.ids.slide.load_previous()
        self.root.ids.info.text_color = 0,0,0,1
        self.root.ids.icon.text_color =0,0,0,1
        self.root.ids.progress.value = 0
        self.root.ids.icon.icon = "numeric-1-circle"

    def previous1(self):
        self.root.ids.slide.load_previous()
        self.root.ids.address.text_color = 0,0,0,1
        self.root.ids.icon1.text_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
        self.root.ids.progress1.value = 0
        self.root.ids.icon1.icon = "numeric-2-circle"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    customer_page().run()
```

The console repeatedly gives this error:
File "C:\Users\reals\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\reg_customer.kv", line 32, in 
app.next()
File "C:\Users\reals\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\customer.py", line 19, in next
self.root.ids.slide.load_next(mode="next")
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.root` does not point to Screen object with widgets. It points to ScreenManager object which does not have ids attribute. To get specified screen from ScreenManager object you can use `get_screen('screen_name')` method.

Replace all `self.root` occurences with `self.root.get_screen('customer')`